# subobject in Set

Tags: category-theory, monomorphisms

I cannot compute  the coequaliser of $s$ and $id_M$ in $\mathbf{Set}$:
My problem is that if $s$ switches $a$ and $b$ in $M=\{a,b\}$ how will then look the coequaliser $M \rightrightarrows M \to U$ where on the l.h.s. is $s$ and $id_M$.I.e. how will look $U$ and the arrow $e$ to it ? Whenever I choose $U=M$ and $e=id_M$ or $e=s$ then neither choice gives when composed the same arrow.

Comment: Coequalizer of $f,g:A\rightarrow B$ in $\mathbf{Set}$ is calculated by taking $B$ and quotient by the equivalence relation generated by $f(a)\cong g(a)$, for all $a\in A$. In particular, if $g=\text{id}$ and $f=s:\{0,1\}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ swaps $0,1$, then $0=\text{id}(0)$ is identified with $s(0)=1$, so the coequalizer is $\{*\}$ and the $e:M\rightarrow\{*\}$ the unique map